# For symmetric, non-singular, positive definite matrix $B$ and some unit vector $u$ show $u^T Bu \ge \frac{1}{ {\lVert B^{-1} \rVert} }$

Tags: linear-transformations, inner-products, symmetric-matrices, positive-definite

> For symmetric non-singular positive definite matrix $B$, and any unit vector ${\lVert u \rVert} = 1$, show that:
>
> \begin{gather*}
>   u^T Bu \ge \frac{1}{ {\lVert B^{-1} \rVert} }
> \end{gather*}

Since $B$ is positive definite, we know that:

\begin{gather*}
  u^T Bu > 0 \\
\end{gather*}

That and the Cauchy Schwarz Inequality give us:

\begin{gather*}
  0 < u^T Bu \le {\lVert Bu \rVert} \le {\lVert B \rVert} \\
\end{gather*}

For any invertible matrix:

\begin{gather*}
  {\lVert B^{-1} \rVert} {\lVert B \rVert} \ge 1, \quad
  \frac{1}{ {\lVert B^{-1} \rVert} } \le {\lVert B \rVert} \\
\end{gather*}

I'm stuck on what to try from here.

Answer (score 2):

Using Cauchy Schwarz we have,
\begin{align*}
1 = u^{\top} u = \langle B^{1/2}u, B^{-1/2}u\rangle \leq (u^{\top} B u) \cdot (u^{\top} B^{-1} u) \leq (u^{\top} B u) \cdot \|B^{-1}\|.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain $u^{\top} u = \langle B^{1/2}u, B^{-1/2}u\rangle$ and $\langle B^{1/2}u, B^{-1/2}u\rangle \leq (u^{\top} B u) \cdot (u^{\top} B^{-1} u)$?

Comment: $\langle B^{1/2} u, B^{-1/2}u \rangle = (B^{1/2} u)^{\top} (B^{-1/2} u) = u^{\top} B^{1/2} B^{-1/2} u = u^{\top}u$. In the third equality, we used that $B$ is symmetric. Using Cauchy Schwarz, $\langle B^{1/2} u, B^{-1/2}u \rangle \leq \|B^{1/2} u\|^2 \cdot \|B^{-1/2}u\|^2 = (u^{\top} B u) \cdot (u^{\top} B^{-1/2} u)$.